# MySQL get dates from a range for which the records does not exist in the database table

Tags: mysql, sqldatetime

I've a database table as below:

```
 Sales Table 
id  product_id  for_date
 1          10  2019-01-03
 2          12  2019-01-05
 3          16  2019-01-10
```

I want to get dates from between a custom date range for which there are no records in the table. For eg. I want to get the dates from 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-31 on which there were no sales i.e all dates from 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-31 excluding 2019-01-03, 2019-01-05, 2019-01-10. 
Can anyone help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 2):

Typical solutions for this would include a calendar table, that stores all the dates for which you want to check whether an order exists.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can easily generate the calendar table using a recursive query.

Consider:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select '2019-01-01' dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < '2019-01-31'
)
select c.dt 
from cte c
left join sales s on s.for_date = c.dt
where s.for_date is null
```

Note: if performance matters, you would better materialize the calendar table (ie storing it as a table) instead of generating it on the fly. The same recursive query can be used for this:

```
create table mycalendar as 
with recursive cte as (
    select '2019-01-01' dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < '2019-01-31'
)
select * from cte;
```

And then:

```
select c.dt 
from mycalendar c
left join sales s on s.for_date = c.dt
where s.for_date is null
```